# React projects, sharing between multiple computers

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, google-drive-api

I work from home and from my office on the same projects using Visual Studio Code and Google Drive. Generally this has never been an issue, but unfortunately the React applications have a billion files and it seems that it causes some issues while uploading to Google Drive. What alternatives do I have? Thank you.

Comment: You can use a version control system like `git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a source control (such as Azure DevOps, GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket,...) to store your source. In another hand, if you want to store your source on Google Drive, please ignore somes folder named "node_modules", "dist" or "build".

Comment: Even with other source control you need to ignore node_modules, dist and build folders.